# How to calculate average access time of three level cache?

Tags: caching, cpu-architecture

So on the website [GeekForGeek](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multilevel-cache-organisation/) I found this formula to find the find the Average memory access time for a multi-level cache:

```
Tavg = H1 * C1 + (1 – H1) * (H2 * C2 +(1 – H2) *M ) 

where 
H1 is the Hit rate in the L1 caches. 
H2 is the Hit rate in the L2 cache. 
C1 is the Time to access information in the L1 caches. 
C2 is the Miss penalty to transfer information from the L2 cache to an L1 cache. 
M is the Miss penalty to transfer information from the main memory to the L2 cache.
```

But I wonder if you have an L3, will it be this?:

```
Tavg = H1 * C1 + (1 – H1) * (H2 * C2 +(1 – H2) *M )  * (H3 * C3+(1-H3)*M3)

where 
H3 is the Hit rate in the L3 cache. 
C3 is the Miss penalty to transfer information from the L3 cache to an L2 cache. 
M3 is the Miss penalty to transfer information from the main memory to the L3 cache.
```

It doesn't seemed right, Especially since L3 is often a cache for the whole chip rather than just a L2 back up (from what I understand.)

On another site I found this [here](https://testbook.com/question-answer/in-a-three-level-memory-hierarchy-the-access-time--5f9bdd9654d2d6eb575e3866) :

```
Tavg = H1*T1+(1-H1)H2(T1+T2)+(1-H1)(1-H2)(T1+T2+T3)
```

But that doesn't seemed right either, the only thing from L3 is T3. If it is right, nothing explain why, so I'm confused.

I'm trying to **find the Tavg for when there is a L3 (With L2 and L1) and when it's only L2 and L1.** Any advices is appreciated!

Thank you!

In my research there wasn't much about the access time of L3, Except the las link, but I can't find explanation on the time access with the three levels.

Comment: What makes you think that wouldn't be correct for a shared L3 cache?  You mean because of the possibility of contention, or variable hit times depending on which slice of L3 holds the address, thus a different number of hops over the ring bus (in Intel client CPUs)?  This formula is for the simplest case, simplified for students.  And most textbooks will then ask you to calculate stuff about execution time of a program, assuming a very simplistic CPU with no memory-level parallelism that stalls until a load result arrives.  No hit-under-miss / miss-under-miss, or prefetching.

Comment: If you were to measure on a real CPU, you could get real-world numbers.  But of course the L3 hit time would be (T1+T2+T3) in this formula, since its T3 is the time to probe L3 *after* determining that it's a miss in L2.  Not the total time from starting the load at the L1d cache.  For actual numbers, see https://www.7-cpu.com/cpu/Skylake.html for example.  Or https://www.7-cpu.com/cpu/Skylake_X.html (SKX has much higher L3 latency because the mesh interconnect is slower than the ring bus, with the upside being higher aggregate bandwidth.  Ice Lake-server improved it significantly.)

Comment: Oh, on closer look, that formula with `(T1+T2+T3)` is assuming T3 hits at worst.  As you say, there's no L3 hit ratio, so "T3" is the last level of the memory hierarchy.  Usually that would be DRAM, not a "cache".  So you're correct, that doesn't make sense.  I haven't looked super carefully at your attempt to extend the 2-level formula to 3 levels.